# Looking for longitudinal authentication pattern data

Tags: data-request

I am looking for data containing authentication pattern along with the time. This is basically authentication attempts with timestamp. An authentication attempt could be either logging in to account with password, or register new account with password.

To start with, the dataset should at least contain `time`, which is the time when an attempt has been made.

Ideally, it could also contain e.g. the application of each attempt made to, or the password used in each attempt.

Due to privacy issue, we could also not record password exactly, but differentiate different passwords using id. For example, the ideal data could look like this

```
time               id
9:27  2/12/2015    1
12:27 2/13/2015    1
14:00 2/13/2015    2
```

In this example, this person make one authentication attempt with one password around 9am on Feb. 12, and another attempt with the same password at 12pm, Feb. 13. Then, he/she make one more attempt with another password around 2pm on Feb. 13.